# Where is the source code for Airflow backport providers?

Tags: airflow

I'm looking to edit some code for https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-google/2021.3.3/ as I need to use Google Ads Python SDK >= 15 and theres a requirement on the backport provider of google-ads<8.0 during my migration from 1.10.15 to 2.0.

The source code linked goes directly to the apache/airflow/providers which seems to be the same for https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-google/.

So I'm a bit confused as to what code each package is installing or if it's now the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find specific tag in the source code :

[image]

Specifically for the release you are asking:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/backport-providers-2021.3.3

I assume your question is about are referring to PR [Upgrade to support Google Ads v10](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/22965) This PR will be released with [apache-airflow-providers-google](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-google/) in version 7.0.0
It will not be released for backport providers.

Note that backport providers are for Airflow 1.10 series. Since Airflow 1.10 reached end of life there are no more new releases for it - thus there are also no more backport provider releases.